# Why won't the domainupdown control change the value until the down arrow is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am adding a DomainUpdown control as well as its list of items to display programmatically.  I've also done it using the toolbox with the same results.

Here is some sample code that illustrates the behavior:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  GroupBox groupbox1 = new GroupBox();
  this.Controls.Add(groupbox1);
  DomainUpDown dup = new DomainUpDown();
  dup.Items.Add("one");
  dup.Items.Add("two");
  dup.Items.Add("three");
  dup.Wrap = true;
  dup.Text = "two";
  groupbox1.Controls.Add(dup);
}
```

When I run the program and click the up arrow, nothing happens.  The only way to get the control to begin working is to click the down arrow.  Once that has happened the control works as advertised.

Any ideas on why this might happen?

Comment: That is not the standard behavior.  What are you doing in the DomainUpDown1_Change method?

Comment: I'm reading several of the properties of the control but I'm not assigning it anything.  The text in the control is a lookup into a table.  I take the value the user selected, use it as an index into the table and send the looked-up value to the server.  I saw an example where they were assigning the value of the text in that method.  Should I be doing that?  It seems to work without it - except for the first time of course.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem.  Try posting code that duplicates the problem so users can see how it happens.

Comment: That Lars, I believe I may have found the problem but do not have time to test it as I have been working on other things.  My belief is that the tree panel has focus and when I click on the DUP all it does is remove focus from the tree panel to the other control panel.  I tried changing focus manually but that didn't work.  If I still can't get it I'll try to create a smaller copy that exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Hi LarsTech,  my idea did not work so I've played around with it some more.  The above code behaves in the same way my program does so I don't think it is a problem with my code.  I started a new 'solution' and pasted the code above.  Give it a shot and tell me if you see the same behavior if you don't mind.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
//dup.Text = "two";
dup.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

By setting the index instead of the Text property, the up down buttons can properly move to the appropriate index in the list.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks LT!  I have spent two days trying to find the answer.  I appreciate your time.